# Modificar la estructura de un STORED Procedure cambiar la utilizacion de cursores

Tags: sql, sql-server, script

Quisiera que me ayudaran a cambiar la estructura de un sp de pasarlo de cursor a otro método ya que demora demasiado tiempo. Quisiera que me ayudara a como poder cambiar de cursor a tablas temporales o algún otro método existente para reemplazar cursores.

Les dejo el sp original:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ejercicio1
(
  @ID_PROCESO   INT
, @MODO_PROCESO INT
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ID_PV INT;
DECLARE @COD_ITEM INT;
DECLARE @COD_IND_COB INT;
DECLARE @COD_RAMO INT;
DECLARE @AUX_EJERCICIO INT;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE cursor_uno CURSOR
FOR SELECT id_pv
         , cod_item
         , cod_ind_cob
         , cod_ramo
           FROM wp_reasauto with(Nolock)
           WHERE id_proceso = @ID_PROCESO;
OPEN cursor_uno;
FETCH cur_wp_reas INTO @ID_PV
                     , @COD_ITEM
                     , @COD_IND_COB
                     , @COD_RAMO;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @MODO_PROCESO IN(3, 4, 7)
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_ejercicio_reas @ID_PV
                             , @COD_ITEM
                             , @COD_IND_COB
                             , @COD_RAMO
                             , 0
                             , @EJERCICIO = @AUX_EJERCICIO OUTPUT;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_ejercicio @ID_PV
                        , @COD_ITEM
                        , @COD_IND_COB
                        , @COD_RAMO
                        , 0
                        , @EJERCICIO = @AUX_EJERCICIO OUTPUT;
    END;

    UPDATE wp_reasauto
           SET ejercicio = @AUX_EJERCICIO
        WHERE   id_proceso = @ID_PROCESO 
            and id_pv = @ID_PV 
            and cod_item = @COD_ITEM 
            and cod_ind_cob = @COD_IND_COB;

    FETCH cursor_uno INTO @ID_PV
                        , @COD_ITEM
                        , @COD_IND_COB
                        , @COD_RAMO;
END;
CLOSE cursor_uno;
DEALLOCATE cursor_uno;

END;
```

Agradezco su valioso apoyo. Me colaboran por favor con este inconveniente que tengo esto ya que se me ha encomendado la tarea de mejorar los procesos de la base de datos y he detectado un uso exagerado de cursores dentro de la base de datos.

Comment: Un stored procedure, que lo que hace es llamar a otros stored procedure, tal cuál muestras, es algo procedimental. Eso no puede mejorar mucho, salvo que muestres lo que hacen los otros procedimientos, y entonces se intente aplicar lógica de conjuntos.

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero revisar el proceso completo (del SP que muestras y los que invocas) de ser posible crear crear dos tablas temporales para el `IF @MODO_PROCESO IN(3, 4, 7)` y su `ELSE` así realizar la misma operación pero masivamente por cada SP; y desde luego el `UPDATE` que muestras.

Comment: Imagino que el trabajo pesado lo hace el SP que se invoca dentro del cursor. ¿Que es lo que hace este Sp? sin tener el código de este es imposible decirte como evitar el uso del cursor

Answer (score 0):

Además de lo que hagan los dos procedimientos a los que llama este primero, que son la parte importante para poder eliminar los cursores, tienes dos puntos de mejora en el mismo.

La definición del cursor para tratar una lectura de tabla que has definido con el hint (noLock), es mejorable.

[Declare Cursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Impacto de cursor Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)

En vez de realizar una update para la última tabla por cada iteración del cursor, puedes alimentar una variable tipo tabla, y realizar solo una update.

La mejora sustancial, se producirá sobre todo en los bloqueos, que tenga la tabla wp_reasauto.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ejercicio1
(
  @ID_PROCESO   INT
, @MODO_PROCESO INT
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ID_PV INT;
DECLARE @COD_ITEM INT;
DECLARE @COD_IND_COB INT;
DECLARE @COD_RAMO INT;
DECLARE @AUX_EJERCICIO INT;

DECLARE @TABLEUPDATE TABLE  (
  AUX_EJERCICIO INT
, ID_PROCESO INT
, ID_PV INT
, COD_ITEM INT
, COD_IND_COB INT
);
            
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Es mucho más rápido. Evalúa las diferentes opciones, en la documentación.
DECLARE cursor_uno CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL  
FOR SELECT id_pv
         , cod_item
         , cod_ind_cob
         , cod_ramo
           FROM wp_reasauto with(Nolock)
           WHERE id_proceso = @ID_PROCESO;

OPEN cursor_uno;
FETCH cur_wp_reas INTO @ID_PV
                     , @COD_ITEM
                     , @COD_IND_COB
                     , @COD_RAMO;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @MODO_PROCESO IN(3, 4, 7)
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_ejercicio_reas @ID_PV
                             , @COD_ITEM
                             , @COD_IND_COB
                             , @COD_RAMO
                             , 0
                             , @EJERCICIO = @AUX_EJERCICIO OUTPUT;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_ejercicio @ID_PV
                        , @COD_ITEM
                        , @COD_IND_COB
                        , @COD_RAMO
                        , 0
                        , @EJERCICIO = @AUX_EJERCICIO OUTPUT;
    END;
    INSERT INTO @TABLEUPDATE (AUX_EJERCICIO, ID_PROCESO, ID_PV, COD_ITEM, COD_IND_COB)
    VALUES
    (@AUX_EJERCICIO, @ID_PROCESO,@ID_PV,@COD_ITEM,@COD_IND_COB)

    FETCH cursor_uno INTO @ID_PV
                        , @COD_ITEM
                        , @COD_IND_COB
                        , @COD_RAMO;
END;
CLOSE cursor_uno;
DEALLOCATE cursor_uno;
    UPDATE w
           SET ejercicio = T.AUX_EJERCICIO
           FROM wp_reasauto w INNER JOIN @TABLEUPDATE T 
                     ON T.AUX_EJERCICIO = w.AUX_EJERCICIO
                    AND T.ID_PROCESO = W.ID_PROCESO 
                    AND T.ID_PV = w.id_pv
                    AND T.COD_ITEM = W.cod_item
                    AND T.COD_IND_COB = W.COD_IND_COB


END;
```